# Travis CI command is not available from console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, continuous-integration

I've installed the travis gem

```
gem install travis
```

Gem was installed successful, but `travis login` is not available from console (Ubuntu). Output tells that `travis` application is not installed and I can install it with `sudo apt-get install travis`. But it's not that Travis CI I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ruby -S travis login` works fine